# How to update database values for a whole day

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, web-applications

I am building a web application, for travelling. I have managed to get users to be able to insert how much they have spent on each category (i.e. travel, accomodation, food, etc) into the database once from a form. However, I want them to be able to contiously add to the total value of each category for just that day using the same form, and then everyday have a new total for each category as well.
I'm not quite sure how I would do that at the moment.
Here is my code so far for inserting the values into the database from my form (which works):

```
if(isset($_POST['addinfo_button'])){
    $Food = $_POST['food'];
    $Transport = $_POST['transport'];
    $Accom = $_POST['accomodation'];
    $Entertain = $_POST['entertainment'];
    $Souvenir = $_POST['souvenirs'];    
    $Misc = $_POST['miscellaneous'];    
    $Date = date("Y-m-d");
    $Trip_id;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE id =$user_id_session AND date1 <= '$Date' && date2 >= '$Date'";
        $records = mysql_query($sql); 
        while($trip=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
        $Trip_id = $trip['trip_id'];    
        }
    $foreignkey = $user_info['id'];

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO todays_spend (food, transport, accomodation, entertainment, souvenirs, miscellaneous,date, trip_id, id)Values('{$Food}', '{$Transport}', '{$Accom}', '{$Entertain}','{$Souvenir}', '{$Misc}','{$Date}','{$Trip_id}','{$foreignkey}')"); 

    header('Location: budgetbuddy.php');    
}
```

Would I have to do something similar to this? or modify this one slightly?

Comment: Here comes SQL-injection.

Comment: Is `$con` a `mysql_` connection or another driver? Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Comment: if you want them to add, then you need to UPDATE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

Comment: $con is a mysql connection

Answer (score 0):

Could not write code for you. But I can give you an Idea how you can achieve this having only one form. 
Create a table with your needs.I mean your entertainement, food, etc along with their name and Id.  If you can make user enter their name or anything that users can uniquely identified. Then things go easier. When a user enter their how much they spent insert into table along with their name or identifier. Next time same user enter details simply find if already user has anything updated on same day , if user added anything before simply update the table by adding previously existing values to new values. Update them. Now you easily even find how much each user spent on particuler catogery.Hope it helps. Thank you.